# Twilio mobile number verification - VerificationCheck was not found on Express

Tags: express, twilio

The requested resource /Services/serviceSSID/VerificationCheck was not found is the eroor showing in the console
my code is

```js
otpLogin:async (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.otp);
    try {
        const isOTP = await client.verify.services(serviceSSID).verificationChecks.create({
            to:`+91${req.body.phone}`,
            code:req.body.otp
        })  
        if(isOTP)console.log(isOTP);
        return res.status(200).json({message:" mobile number verified"})       
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        return res.status(500).json({message:"something went wrong"})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check#check-a-verification):

> Twilio deletes the verification SID once it’s:
>
> - expired (10 minutes)
> - approved
> - when the max attempts to check a code have been reached
>
> If any of these occur, verification checks will return a 404 not found error like this:
>
> ```
> Unable to create record: The requested resource /Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VerificationCheck was not found
> ```
>
> If you’d like to double check what happened with a given verification - please use the logs found in the Twilio Console under your Verification Service:
>
> [image]

I've found that if you submit a form twice by clicking a submit button twice quickly, that the verification is successfully checked and then because it was a success deleted, then the second check fails with a 404 like this and that is the error result you see. To avoid this, you should stop users from being able to submit the form twice by disabling the submit button after the first attempt.

Comment: when this error response is removed....when can I check my code again in other words? Is it sth permanent once one of the 3 criteria is met?